# Is there a way to index a complete site but to make searches point always to index.html?

Tags: seo, google

I have a small site with 10 pages and all of them contain related content. When doing searches with Google the results seem to have random pages (I know that they are not random but I don't know why Google chooses them and they look random to me).

Is there a way to make Google show in the results only the main page of the domain?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. Google indexes and ranks individual pages. If a page is relevant for a user search than that page is displayed in the search results. It runs counter to the search engine's goals, and the user's searching goals, to show a completely different page in the search results than the one that has the content the user is looking for.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then the point is understanding why Google points wherever it does. It is a learning site and it has a theory page, a step by step tutorial page, an exercises page and an examples page. Searching words that appear on the title of all pages gives results pointing to any of these pages

Comment: "words that appear on the title of all pages" - but presumably the page content varies and users perhaps link to some pages more than others. What page would _you_ expect Google to return in this instance and why? Why do you have the same words in the title on all pages?